# What is the correct translation for "Get ideas to create objectives" in German?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

What's the correct translation for "Get ideas to create objectives"?

> Hole dir Ideen um Ziele zu entwickeln.

or

> Hole dir Ideen zum Formulieren von Zielen.

And what's the difference in meaning?

Comment: What does it mean in English?

Comment: The context of the phrase in English is as follows: you are given a list of goals/objectives that you can use or come up with your own goal based on the provided list.

Comment: So I am *given* a few ideas or suggestions or words in order to come up with (my own?) objectives?

Comment: I'd say ideas. You are given a list of the most commonly used goals, which you can use or use this list just for inspiration and come up with something of your own.

Comment: I'm a native English speaker and I'm also having a hard time understanding the sentence. It reminds me of type of thing you'd see in a management seminar. In any case, this site usually does not do straight translation requests. Also, see choXer's answer for why *holen* is probably not the right verb here.

Comment: The English sentence is way too broad to understand without more context imho. What action does "get" stand for here? How exactly do you "create objectives"? The existing answers are poking in the fog of vague context.

Answer (score 2):

Mein Vorschlag ist:

> Sammle Ideen, um Ziele zu finden.

für

> Get ideas to create objectives.

Dagegen gefällt mir

> Hole dir Ideen um Ziele zu entwickeln.

weniger gut. Ideen holen - das klingt, als lägen sie irgendwo bereit. Man holt sich was aus dem Kühlschrank. Und "Ziele entwickeln" klingt etwas feierlich/gestelzt, ist aber womöglich gewollt. Ich vermute "objectives" ist Manager- oder Beratersprache und da passt "entwickeln" ziemlich gut, und "goals" wäre umgangssprachlicher.

> Hole dir Ideen zum Formulieren von Zielen.

Da liegt die Betonung m.E. zu sehr auf dem Formulieren. Man hat die Ziele schon, aber sucht noch nach dem richtigen Ausdruck?

"Ziele festlegen" wäre noch ein gängiger Terminus, bei dem weniger Schreibtisch mitschwingt.

Answer (score 1):

**Q: What's the correct translation for "Get ideas to create objectives"?**

A: There isn't a *single* correct translation, since both *to get an idea* and *to create objectives* can be translated (as you noted correctly) equivalently with

- auf eine Idee kommen, eine Idee erhalten, Ideen sammeln, and more
- Ziele setzen, entwickeln, formulieren, and more.

I'd prefer

> Komm auf Ideen, um Ziele zu setzen!

This relies on "*auf eine Idee kommen"*, which is a phraseme, and on "*(sich) ein Ziel setzen*", which is a phraseme as well. Also, it copies the original's imperative form by lack of a (personal) pronoun. This may however go against the concept of involvement; in that case, I'd go with

> Komm auf Ideen, um Dir Ziele zu setzen!

---

**Q: And what's the difference in meaning?**

A: The semantic difference between

> Hole dir Ideen, um Ziele zu entwickeln. /
> Komm auf Ideen, um Ziele zu entwickeln.

and

> Hole dir Ideen zum Formulieren von Zielen. /
> Komm auf Ideen zum Formulieren von Zielen.

lies in the semantics of *to develop* and *to formulate*, which is minimal in the given context; both refer to the conceptual (thus cognitive) workload of coming up with objectives, goals, targets and the like. *Formulate* perhaps implies one more step, that is to bring "into form" what was only collected so far; that is, if "develop" would not stress this out as well (I'd say it does, but it may be understood as a bit closer to a mere brainstorming).

The syntactic difference between the use of an infinite clause with *um ... zu* and the nominalization in *zum Formulieren* is also negligible for the transportation of what you want to say. The mutual syntactic attention lies in "zu" = *(in order) to*, leading to the intention of "getting ideas" in the first place, in other words answering why one would "get ideas".

Answer (score 1):

The difference between "formulate" ([formulieren](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/formulieren)) and "develop" ([entwickeln](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/entwickeln)) in this context is not particularly great. "Formulate" sounds more 'technical' to me and involves writing things down (or is more precise). As far as I know, this difference also exists in English.

As you can see here ([holen](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/holen#German)), the meaning of "holen" is not as broad as "[get](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/get)". Without knowing the exact context, I can note that "holen" only makes sense if there is a practical activity associated with it (getting up and walking across the room to pick up a card from the table or similar).

Comment: The English *to get* is very broad and I'm tempted to say that the sentence should be rephrased to make the intended meaning clear. But yes, *holen* sounds wrong, unless you have ideas printed on cards in a stack somewhere, and you have to physically pick them up to read them.

Answer (score 1):

I would translate this as "Finde Ideen zur Zielsetzung" oder "Finde Ideen, um (dir) Ziele zu setzen".  The "dir" is optional.